# Display State Picklist Values in Custom LWC Record-Edit-Form

Tags: lightning-web-components, country-and-state, lightning-record-form

I have a custom LWC that displays contact information to edit. One of the fields is the MailingState. Currently this field is a standard input field but I would like it to display as a picklist. Its my understanding that it will display as a picklist if you pass the record-type-id if there are multiple record Types. I have implemented State Picklist for Salesforce. I have checked the field outside of the custom lwc and it is a picklist.

Here is the LWC:

```
                            <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordEditId} record-type-id={defaultRecordType} object-api-name="Contact">

                                <!-- Lightning Messages Display -->
                                <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>

                                <!-- Contact Edit Form -->
                                <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">

                                    <div class="slds-col">

                                        <lightning-input-field data-field="FirstName" field-name="FirstName">
                                        </lightning-input-field>

                                        <lightning-input-field data-field="Title" field-name="Title">
                                        </lightning-input-field>

                                        <lightning-input-field data-field="MobilePhone" field-name="MobilePhone">
                                        </lightning-input-field>

                                        <lightning-input-field data-field="Social_Security_Number__c"
                                            field-name="Social_Security_Number__c">
                                        </lightning-input-field>

                                        <lightning-input-field data-field="HomePhone" field-name="HomePhone">
                                        </lightning-input-field>

                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Contact Edit Form -->

                                    <div class="slds-col">

                                        <lightning-input-field data-field="LastName" field-name="LastName">
                                        </lightning-input-field>

                                        <lightning-input-field data-field="Email" field-name="Email">
                                        </lightning-input-field>

                                        <lightning-input-field data-field="Birthdate" field-name="Birthdate">
                                        </lightning-input-field>

                                        <lightning-input-field data-field="Ownership_Percentage__c"
                                            field-name="Ownership_Percentage__c">
                                        </lightning-input-field>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <hr>

                                <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">

                                    <div class="slds-col">

                                        <!-- <lightning-input-field data-field="MailingAddress" field-name="MailingAddress">
                                        </lightning-input-field> -->

                                        <lightning-input-field data-field="MailingStreet" field-name="MailingStreet"></lightning-input-field>

                                        <lightning-input-field data-field="MailingCity" field-name="MailingCity"></lightning-input-field>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">

                                    <div class="slds-col">

                                        <lightning-input-field data-field="MailingPostalCode" field-name="MailingPostalCode"></lightning-input-field>
                                        
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="slds-col">

                                        <lightning-input-field data-field="MailingState" field-name="MailingState"></lightning-input-field>
                                        
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

I would like it to look like this (mirroring standard salesforce):

[image]

- Orginally we did not have a record type for the contact object and it did not work, so I implemented an RT to try and resolve.
- **All Documentation I have found states something along the lines of**: 'If your org uses record types, picklist fields display values according to your record types. You must provide a record type ID using the record-type-id attribute if you have multiple record types on an object and you don’t have a default record type. Otherwise, the default record type ID is used.'

The Record Type is getting populated as well with the following:

```
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CONTACT_OBJECT })
    getContactData({error,data}){
        if(data){
            console.log('Default RT: ', data.defaultRecordTypeId);
            this.defaultRecordType = data.defaultRecordTypeId;
            console.log('RecordTypes: ', JSON.stringify(data.recordTypeInfos));
            console.log(data);
        }
        else if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$defaultRecordType', fieldApiName: STATE_FIELD })
    setPicklistOptions({error, data}) {
      if (data) {
        console.log('Picklist Data:');
        console.log(data);
        this.stateValues = data.values;
        console.log(this.stateValues);
      } else if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

1. Has anyone has experience with displaying a picklist field in a lightning-record-edit form?
2. Is this an issue because of the state picklist?

** I just tested this with another custom picklist field on the object and it displayed the input field as a picklist. So this is an issue with just the state picklist field. Is this a bug or expected functionality?

Answer (score 3):

If you've enabled the State/Country Picklist feature, then you have to use the Code fields in Contact and Account (like MailingStateCode instead of MailingState).  See this [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329128&type=1&mode=1).

> Developers need to append the word 'code' to the picklist fields in
> their Apex Code, when the above feature is Enabled